# What happens to the iterator if the underlaying container is changed?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

What happens to an iterator if the container that it iterates over is changed?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
    it++;
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
    v.emplace_back(4);
    it++;
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
    it++;
    std::cout << *it << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1
2
12230672 // every time you run you get a different value.
0
```

Comment: It becomes invalid. That is stated in many places. E.g.:

Comment: @Keloo No, it is not necessary to delete this question. Duplicate questions are good for SEO.

Comment: Note that "just changing" the underlying container does not necessarily invalidate an iterator.  It depends on the change.

Comment: What happens if you are in a range loop and the container is changed by another thread? (the reason why I'm asking)

Comment: @Keloo If you read any variable while a different thread is changing it, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Keloo If you have a substantially different question you need to ask, you should post it as a new question, instead of trying to iterate on versions of the question in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator is invalidated. That means (tautology alert!) that it is no longer valid, and indirecting through it is undefined behavior.

This can happen for a vector when appending (in your case, via `emplace_back`) causes the internal storage for the vector to be reallocated.

See [the draft standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.modifiers) for more.

Comment: strictly speaking this is wrong for `emplace_back`. Iterators are only invalidated when the new size() is greater than capacity(), if not only the `end` iterator is invalidated.. or cppreference is wrong, which is of course possible...